# FutureBuilder/StreamBuilder called unnecessary times when Navigator.push?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

My `FutureBuilder/StreamBuilder` called unnecessary times when navigating using `push`. Is it possible to stop without change `navigator.push`?

```
 Stream<List<Categorie>> getFromBloc;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    getFromBloc = getData();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

inside `state`, outside `build` method

```
  Stream<List<Categorie>> getData()=>
     _categoryBloc.category;
```

**build method**

```
   StreamBuilder(
        stream: getFromBloc,//_categoryBloc.category,
        builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<List<Categorie>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
               ...
          } else {
            ...
            GestureDetector(
              child:...,
              onTap:(){
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/subCategory',arguments: Arguments(postModel: post));
              }
          }
        })
```

I added debug point inside `streamBuilder`. when navigating it's running multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

pushNamed is being called every time *getFromBloc* stream changes (gets new data). You shouldn't call it anywhere inside build function at all. You might want to do it like this:

```dart
getFromBloc.first.then((data) => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/subCategory',arguments: Arguments(postModel: post)))
```

For example, you can do it in initState. Callback will be executed only once after getFromBloc stream gets a new value.

**UPD**: I got you wrong. Every time you push a new route not just StreamBuilder gets rebuild, but every page on the stack rebuilds to update the back button. There's an [issue](http://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655) for that.

> This is working as intended. In general, you should assume that all
>   widgets can rebuild at any time, that they don't is mostly just an
>   optimisation.
>
> In particular, routes will rebuild because their navigator state has
>   changed so they might need to update how they draw back buttons and
>   the like.

Comment: please check my question again.. I navigate when tap button.